# My Javascript Origin and Redirect URL for Google Sign In

Tags: google-oauth

I am trying to use sign in with google credential in MyWeb application. I develop MyWeb application using Netbeans PHP. In the developer google console I set up the project and fill in the APIs & auth Credential.

For the Javascript origin field I uselocalhost:8080 
For the Redirect URl field I use localhost/MyWeb

I call the google api from my index.php page when I click the google sign-in button I get an error message of "Origin Mismatch".

What should be my Javascript origin field value, how can i find out its value
and should the Redirect URl field be localhost/MyWeb/index instead?

Please help!
Best regards,
Nik